# How do you calculate a boolean aggregate over a column in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, google-bigquery

I have a table of events of users, and I want to project those events into a
new column with some predicate, and then aggregate the events together per user
into a new projection that tells me if a user has ever had the predicate match
for them, or if they've never had it match, etc.

In other languages this is usually called `all()` and `any()`, where you pass
it a list of boolean values and it will tell you if all of them match, or if at
least one matches.  It's equivalent to using a boolean `AND` on all boolean
values (such as in the case with `all`) or using a boolean `OR` on all boolean
values (as in `any`).

Does BigQuery have this feature?  I can sort of approximate it using `max` and
`min` but it's not ideal.

Example:

```
select
month(date_time) m,
count(*) as ct,
max(id_is_present),
min(id_is_present),
max(starts_with_one) max_one,
min(starts_with_one) min_one,
from
(
    select
    length(user_id) > 1 id_is_present,
    regexp_match(user_id, r'^1') starts_with_one,
    date_time
    from
    [user_events.2015_02]
)
group by
m
```

It's exploiting a behavior of `max(true, false, false)` yielding `true`, so you could sort of implement `any` and `all` by searching through the column for values and then building from there.

Is this the hack I have to rely on or does BigQuery support boolean aggregates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, BigQuery has such aggregation functions, it uses SQL Standard names for them:

```
EVERY (will do logical and)
SOME (will do logical or)
```

Answer (score 7):

In case someone else stumbles across this, standard SQL offers `logical_and()` and `logical_or`.  So, the code could be written as:

```
select month(date_time) as m, count(*) as ct,
       logical_or(id_is_present),
       logical_and(id_is_present),
       logical_or(starts_with_one) as max_one,
       logical_and(starts_with_one) min_one,
from (select length(user_id) > 1 id_is_present,
             regexp_match(user_id, r'^1') starts_with_one,
             date_time
      from [user_events.2015_02]
      ) u
group by m;
```